# Paste range items into columns VBA

Tags: excel, collections, vba

I have 14 range items in a collection that I am trying to copy and paste into a new sheet one after the other, in different columns.  I have written a for loop below but for some reason it keeps breaking on the line where I select the new column and I am not sure why. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
Set NewBook = Workbooks.Add

    With NewBook
        .SaveAs Filename:="NewReport.xls"
    End With

Count = 1

For Each rngitem In rngcollec

rngitem.Copy
NewBook.Activate
Sheet1.Columns(0, Count).Select
rngitem.Paste

Count = Count + 1

Next
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the paste method dosen't work with column, not in the same way as it does with ranges and cells, you must change your code to this:

(make sure you declared the sheet1 variable since her declaration is not in the part of the code you posted)

```
sheet1.columns(Count).select
'there is no need to declare the row here just

sheet1.paste
```